# XSD allow attribute only depending on other attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd

Suppose I have an XML element, `food`, that can take on one of two forms:

```
<food kind="juice" />
<food kind="fruit" sort="apple" />
```

In my XSD I would like to specify that the `sort` attribute can only exist for the `<food>` element iff the `kind="fruit"`. The attribute `sort` would not be acceptable for other `kind` values. It looks like a [simple attribute implication](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Simple_attribute_implication) might work but I could not find more details on this.

How can I specify such a dependency?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using XSD 1.1's **[Conditional Type Assignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1"> 
  <xs:element name="food">
    <xs:alternative test="@kind = 'juice'" type="JuiceType"/> 
    <xs:alternative test="@kind = 'fruit'" type="FruitType"/>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="JuiceType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- ... -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="FruitType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- ... -->
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="sort"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Do consider, however, an alternative design that's expressible in both XSD 1.1 and 1.0 that's generally preferable:

```
<juice/>
<fruit sort="apple"/>
```

That is, rather than have a `kind` attribute, use the element name to convey kind.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: In OP's case, how do we make validation fail if the attribute `kind` is not one of `{juice, fruit}`?

Comment: @segfault: See my answer to [XSD conditional type assignment default type confusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47866026/290085) for an example.  Thanks.