# XSD conditional type assignment default type confusion?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

I try to design a XSD with CTA. 
I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <person version="1">
        <firstname>toto</firstname>
        <lastname>tutu</lastname>
    </person>
    <person version="2">
        <firstname>toto</firstname>
        <lastname>tutu</lastname>
        <birthdate>2017-12-18</birthdate>
    </person>
</persons>
```

The XSD looks like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1"> 

    <xs:complexType name="person_v1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:token"/>
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:token"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:token" use="required" fixed="1"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="person_v2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:token"/>
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:token"/>
            <xs:element name="birthdate" type="xs:date"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:token" use="required" fixed="2"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:alternative test="@version=1" type="person_v1"/>        
        <xs:alternative test="@version=2" type="person_v2"/>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="persons">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="person" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

The XML is validated against the XSD, but in the XSD:

1. If I delete the version attribute, it validates,
2. If I replace the version 1 by 3, it validates,
3. If I delete all the content of person, it validates.

There must be something missing on my XSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If I delete the version attribute, it validates,

As it should, because when no `xs:alternative` tests match, `person` can be `xs:anyType` per [Common Mapping Rules for Element Declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#dcl.elt.common).

> 2. If I replace the version 1 by 3, it validates,

As it should for the same reason as #1.

> 3. If I delete all the content of person, it validates.

No, it doesn't.  You may not have truly associated the XML document with your XSD, or you may have accidently combined experiment #3 with experiments #1 or #2.

### Updated XSD

The following updated XSD specifies a default type of `person` rather than `xs:anyType` to avoid the surprises #1 and #2.  Note that it also uses extension to consolidate common parts of the declarations of `person_v1` and `person_v2` into `person_v` and to satisfy the requirement that the alternative types must be derived from a common base class.  (When unspecified, it's `xs:anyType` and typically goes unnoticed.)

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1"> 
  <xs:complexType name="person_v">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:token"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:token"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:token" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="person_v1">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="person_v"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="person_v2">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="person_v">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="birthdate" type="xs:date"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="person" type="person_v">
    <xs:alternative test="@version=1" type="person_v1"/>        
    <xs:alternative test="@version=2" type="person_v2"/>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="persons">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="person" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**Update:** Here's an update to `person_v` to require that version be `1` or `2` to address a concern in the comments:

```
  <xs:complexType name="person_v">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:token"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:token"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="version" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
          <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
          <xs:maxInclusive value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I tried your XSD. It works better but still not like expected. Indeed, if I change version="1" by version="3", it still validates, But, if I change the version 2 by another version number, it does not validate.

Comment: @lovelace63: That's easily enough addressed by modifying `person_v` to restrict `version` to be either 1 or 2.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you very much